# rust macro, how to control the different vec have the same length?

Tags: rust, macros

code first:

```
use std::collections::HashMap;
 macro_rules! arr{
    ([$($t:expr=>[$($c:expr),*]),*]) => {
       vec![
            $({
                let mut m = HashMap::new();
                m.insert($t, vec![$($c),*]);
                m
            }),*
       ]
    };
}

fn main() {
    let a = arr!([
        "A"=>[1,2,3],
        "B"=>[3,4]
    ]);
    println!("{:?}", a);
    //print:  [{"A": [1, 2, 3]}, {"B": [3, 4]}]
}
```

I have above macro to generate a vec, contains several HashMap, in which these HashMap value is a vec as well,
{"A": [1, 2, 3]}   => vec value length: 3,
{"B": [3, 4]}   => vec value length: 2,
I wanna all the HashMap have the same length,
how to write in the macro to control this?

Comment: Know that if you want a compile-time check, you will need to use a procedural macro instead of a `macro_rules!` (aka "declarative") macro. Declarative macros *generate* the code at compile time, but it doesn't actually *evaluate* until the code is ran.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the macro so that it creates a block (second set of `{}` encapsulating the macro definition) that you can set helper variables in and do a second pass over your vector, resizing anything that is smaller than the largest array.

In this case I've resized the arrays with the `default` value of the type to keep it simple. You may wish to wrap the data in `Some()`.

This:

```
use std::cmp;
use std::collections::HashMap;
use std::default::Default;

macro_rules! arr{
    ([$($t:expr=>[$($c:expr),*]),*]) => {{
       let mut max = 0;
       let mut result = vec![
            $({
                let mut m = HashMap::new();
                m.insert($t, vec![$($c),*]);
                // Simply unwrap here as we know we inserted at this key above
                max = cmp::max(max, m.get($t).unwrap().len());
                m
            }),*
       ];
       for m in result.iter_mut() {
           for v in m.values_mut() {
               if v.len() < max {
                   v.resize_with(max, Default::default);
               }
           }
       }
       result
    }};
}

fn main() {
    let a = arr!([
        "A"=>[1,2,3],
        "B"=>[3,4]
    ]);
    println!("{:?}", a);
    //print:  [{"A": [1, 2, 3]}, {"B": [3, 4]}]
}
```

Yields:

```
[{"A": [1, 2, 3]}, {"B": [3, 4, 0]}]
```